# how java behave when compile and run on different architecture

Tags: java, x86, jvm, 64-bit, x86-64

Let say i have a application which has a class A.java which only print some info.

So will my application work under:

[1] If i compile `A` with `jdk1.7.x86` and run it with `jre1.7.x64` on a `64 bit` `windows` machine ?

[2] If i compile `A` with `jdk1.7.x64` and run it with `jre1.7.x86` on a `32 bit` `windows` machine ?

[3] If i compile `A` with `jdk1.7.x86` and run it with `jre1.7.x86` on a `64 bit` `windows` machine ?

[4] If i compile `A` with `jdk1.7.x86` and run it with `jre1.7.x64` on a `64 bit` `Linux` machine ?

[5] If i compile `A` with `jdk1.7.x64` and run it with `jre1.7.x86` on a `32 bit` `Linux` machine ?

[6] If i compile `A` with `jdk1.7.x86` and run it with `jre1.7.x86` on a `64 bit` `Linux` machine ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis its not a duplicate see the third point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.class` can run on any JVM which version is greater than the compile version in .class file.

eg:

If java file is compiled by jdk5, all JVM witch version is greater than `1.5` can run this class.

But if compile the java file like this:

```
javac -source 1.4 Your.java
```

The result class can run on JVM who's version is 1.4 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Oui. Si. Igen. Da. Jah. Yebo. Avanu. Ναι. Haan. Ha’an-ji.  نعم. Dah. Of course. Not a problem. Without a doubt. No question. The promise of the Java Runtime Environment is **Write Once, Run Anywhere**.

Linux, Mac, Windows, VMS, Solaris, etc.

Comment: this does not answer the question clearly

Comment: yes true but your statement is true only after you have the correct jre installed for that architecture...see the third point...

Comment: My statement remains true on Windows 7 and 8 given the third point. The only difference will be the amount of memory that is addressable.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: +1 for accuracy and originality